# Retrieve several records using DataView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, dataview

I want to retrieve records in a DataGridView using a DataView. For example, I want to retrieve records of students whose age is between 15 to 18. How do I do that? Below is my code for retrieving a single record only using a DataView:

```
dgvReport.DataSource = new DataView(dt, "StudentID = " + txtSearch.Text, "StudentID", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use RowFilter Property for this

```
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dt);
        dataView.RowFilter  = "age > 14 and age < 19";
        dgvReport.DataSource = dataView;
```

you will get rows with age begining from 15 and ending with 18